# Referencing a C# proc (built in 32 bit environment) from Excel VBA in 64 bit environmemnt

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio

I have an Excel VBA (32 bit) program which calls a procedure developed in C# (Visual Studio 32 bit). I am now migrating the application to a 64 bit environment. I have copied the files generated by VS (32 bit) in the Release directory (`fiskDllLib.dll`,`fiskDllLib.pdb`,`FiskDllLib.tlb`) to the 64 bit computer and in the 64 bit VBE I have referenced `FiskDllLIb.tlb`. When I execute the code shown below I get the following error:
"ActiveX component can't create object".
I want to call from my VBA program, a proc (`copyModelsDirectory`) which is defined in the `fileSys` class in `FiskDllLib`.

I have tried running without `ByVal` spec in procedure declaration and without `PrtSafe` declaration and without any declaration with the same result

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub copyModelsDirectory Lib "FiskDLLlib" (ByVal fromDir As String, ByVal curModel As String, ByVal ftl As Boolean)
#End If

Sub aaaa()
    Dim fs As FiskDLLlib.fileSys

    Set fs = New FiskDLLlib.fileSys
End Sub
```

With this code segment I would just like it to assign the new object to the variable `fs`. There is no output.

Comment: have you tried to recompile your NET dll for 64 bit?

Comment: You cannot load 32-bit executable code into a 64-bit process space or vice versa.

Comment: Can I simply regenerate the C# code in Visual Studio 2019 to overcome the problem